# How Pass ADODB Connection object from VB Components to C# with asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb6, adodb

I am executing multiple vb6 components that accesses different database engines such as access (mdb), sql server, etc from within asp.net.

These components are already compiled dlls in vb6 and added as referenced assembly in asp.net framework 2.0. Each component has several functions that passes the adodb.connection object as parameter and executes sql statements from within these functions.  This is comparable to a layered solution pattern, only, in the business logic layer they pass the adodb.connection object instead of the connection string. This works in VB6 but when called in asp.net it won't work because when the compiler encounters the adodb.connection.open() it modifies the value of the adodb.connection.connectionstring property.

How I get connection string from adodb.connection object

**EDIT**

Here's the `getConnstringfromASP` from comments.

```
public void getConnstringfromASP(ADODB.Connection getadoObjConn)
{
    string strAdoobjConnString = ""; 
    strAdoobjConnString = getadoObjConn.ConnectionString; 
    SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(); 
    objConnection.ConnectionString = strAdoobjConnString;
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem. Could you maybe show the C# code where the problem occurs?

Comment: The below function Called by VB Components.This Function is in C# dll
public void  getConnstringfromASP(ADODB.Connection getadoObjConn)
{
          string strAdoobjConnString = "";
          strAdoobjConnString = getadoObjConn.ConnectionString;
          SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection();
         objConnection.ConnectionString = strAdoobjConnString ;

}

but i Couldn"t assign the ADODB.Connection string to SQLConnection Connecting object.

Comment: Can you show us the value of strAdoobjConnString? What error message do you get when you try to assign `strAdoobjConnString` to `objConnection.ConnectionString`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code for creating the connection string should look something like this:

```
public void getConnstringfromASP(ADODB.Connection getadoObjConn)
{
    string strAdoObjConnString = getadoObjConn.ConnectionString; 

    SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(strAdoObjConnString); 

}
```

the connection string is passed in the constructor of the SqlConnection object.